# Matlab - intersection point between two normal distributions

Tags: matlab, statistics, gaussian

I'm trying to compute the probability of false alarm and probability of detection for a certain detector given H0 and H1. To do so, I compute both pdf's, for H0 and H1. But to compute these probabilities I need to know where both pdf's intersects in order to compute the right tail of H1 and left tail of H0.

[image]

Could you give me any hint to to compute the intersection point between two normal distributions in Matlab?

Edit:

As sugested Ander Biguri I've trtied to compute the crossing point symbolically as:

```
mu1 = 24;
mu2 = 25;
sigma1 = sqrt(0.5);
sigma2 = sqrt(0.5);
dist1 =@(x) exp(-(x-mu1).^2 / (2*sigma1^2)) / sqrt(2*sigma1^2*pi);
dist2 =@(x) exp(-(x-mu2).^2 / (2*sigma2^2)) / sqrt(2*sigma2^2*pi);
fzero(@(x) dist1(x) - dist2(x), rand * (mu1 - mu2) + (mu1 + mu2))
```

but I get that the crossing point is "70". Should I have to normalize? how I can intepret this result?

Edit 2:

I've also tried the fantastic function developed by Douglas Schwarz [Fast and Robust Curve Intersections](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections). But I get too many intersections (since as expected both tails crosses several times when they are close to zero).

Comment: This looks like a thing that would be best solved via maths. Put the equations of 2 gaussians, with different mean and sigma, and just solve for the same value. Or are you OK with just a numerical appoximation?

Comment: I've tried what you told me, but I get a result that I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Because you are computing it numerically. You did not do what I told you.

Comment: Then I didn't understand it well. What did you mean with "solve for the same value"?

Comment: You understood correctly. What you do not understand is that solving something analytically and numerically is a very different thing.  You are solving it numerically, and if you test the answer, its correct (its just no the only solution). What I mean is, take some paper, and solve the equation for the intersection, by hand. Or use symbolic math.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311592/how-to-find-the-point-where-two-normal-distributions-intersect

Comment: But this is not viable in my case, since I have to do it several times for a great amount of simulations. I cannot be solving it by hand each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As supplement material of @Ander Biguri's comment. (unable to comment there)

Please use the following code:

```
fzero(@(x) dist1(x) - dist2(x),25)
```

to replace your last line of "Edit" section. It changes the second argument named "x0" (the point at which fzero begins) only.

There are many zeros of @(x) dist1(x) - dist2(x). fzero begins at "x0" and finds the first zero of the function numerically(the first x satisfy dist1(x) - dist2(x) < Error, actually.). If you want to find a particular zero of the function numerically, you should give a suitable begining point to fzero.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you want to do it several times for a great amount of simulations, maybe you can add some codes rather than a particular begining point like 25. The suitable begining points should locate between mu1 and mu2. And maybe you should consider about the precision of fzero.